# Расчитать размер MP3

Tags: аудио, mp3

Имеется: 
**SampleRate**  ex: 22050 Hz 
**BitRate** ex: 160 kbps    
**Duration**   1000 sec

Хотелось бы формулу для расчета.
Я нагуглил только **Duration***(**BitRate**/8). 
Но хотелось бы знать, будет ли зависеть размер файла от SampleRate. Если да, то какова формула.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bit rate – это же и есть размер-за-время. Умножением на время получается общий размер файла.

Частота дискретизации влияет на размер некомпрессированного файла: нежатый wav 22050 Hz в два раза меньше нежатого wav 44100 Hz.

Comment: спасибо. теперь догнал!